How to decode bytes to characters in a POSIX-compliant way?
I'm attempting to write a strictly POSIX-compliant shell, but the standard doesn't make it clear how to go from bytes to characters. It says to use LC_CTYPE, which further links to the concept of a charmap file, but nowhere is it stated where these charmap files are located and how to read them. man 5 charmap says they are usually located in /usr/share/i18n/charmaps, but that isn't enough for me. Also, on my Linux system, the files in that directory are gzip-encoded, which I think might be non-compliant, but I haven't found anything about it anywhere.
I'm thinking that there must be some standard C utilities to get the details of the current character encoding (otherwise how could anyone ever use it?), but I wasn't able to find anything of the sort in my web search. There are the setlocale and nl_langinfo functions, the latter of which can give you the name of the currently used character encoding, but that doesn't help me with decoding it.
Or am I supposed to know and implement all of them in advance?

Once you have done the setlocale(), MB_CUR_MAX will tell you if you have a multibyte character set or not.
If multibyte, you can use the mb*() POSIX functions such as mbstowcs() to convert multibyte character strings into wide characters.
Then use either the isblank()/isalpha().. vs iswblank()/iswalpha() for instance if you need to know whether a character is a blank/alpha... See iconv() to convert between charsets. All the wc*() functions to work with wide characters (beware not all systems use Unicode codepoints for the wchar_t values).
Characters used in the syntax of the shell itself should be part of the portable charset (ASCII in practice these days) so invariant across locales in practice¹.
A lot of what the shell does is at byte level though, so you may get away in a lot of cases without having to decode. There's also the question of what to do for strings that can't be decoded into characters. Command line arguments don't have to be text or could be text in a variety of different charsets, so shells should be able to deal with that. They should also be able to deal with the locale changing midway through like after export LC_CTYPE=something-else.
For a shell written today, I think I would only support UTF-8 as a multibyte character encoding like mksh does (with -o utf8-mode), a lot of the other multibyte character encoding are dangerous especially in a shell so are best avoided anyway. Then you can do without all that mb* API and do the UTF-8 decoding/encoding by hand.
You'll probably want to check how other shells do, here is not the place to provide a full guide. You'll find that it's often not pretty. For instance bash's pattern matching wrt multibyte handling is pretty awful and not something I'd recommend emulating. Decoding bytes that can't be decoded into characters into special wchar_t values like zsh/python do is likely the best approach at dealing with non-text when you have to do text operation on strings (like pattern matching, cutting, string length...).
Shells that have some level of multibyte support that you may want to look at include bash, zsh, ksh93, mksh, bosh and yash. yash chokes on non-text.

¹ Though POSIX suggests for instance any character considered as blank in the locale can be used as delimiter in the syntax or variable names can be have any alnum, I would strong suggest not going there. Few shells do or only partly and that just makes life harder for yourself and gives users an API that cannot be made reliable. Note that some systems still have locales that have ms-kangi as charset. That charset doesn't have a backslash character and byte 0x5c there is the yen (¥) symbol. You generally get away with it because tools including shells don't really decode bytes into character especially in single-byte locales, so the ¥ can generally be used in place of \ there as tools just attach the backslash meaning to the 0x5c byte.

@PhilipCouling, not sure what you mean, Unicode codepoints range from 0 to 0x10ffff. They will be encoded into a byte or sequence of bytes (multibyte) depending on the locale's charmap. For instance, U+20AC will be encoded as 0xa4 if that's iso8859-1, 0xe2 0x82 0xac for UTF-8 0xa2 0xe3 for GB18030. In all of those locales, mbstowcs() will convert the corresponding sequence of bytes (multi byte string) to a wide character string with one wide char (whose value may or may not be 0x20ac depending on the system). UTF-16 is not relevant as it can't be used as a locale's charmap.

@PhilipCouling, no wchar_t is an opaque type that represents a single character it has nothing to do with UTF-16 (which AFAIK is no used much any longer outside of Java or Microsoft and is a bit of an aberration if you ask me). On GNU system, it matches the Unicode code point regardless of the locale's charset. The wchar_t value for your  U+1F4E6 PACKAGE will be 0x1F4E6. On other systems, YMMV. For instance on FreeBSD, the wchar_t value of U+00E9 (é) will be 0xe9 in a locale using UTF-8 as the charmap (where the encoding is 0xc3 0xa9), and 0xa8a6 in one using  GB18030 (encoding: 0xa8 0xa6).

Okay, that's odd initial references I was reading pointed to wchar_t always being 16 bits not 32. Thanks for discussing.

The locale changing midway through isn't an issue. The standard explicitly states that setting LC_CTYPE doesn't affect the current execution environment (you'll have to start a new shell).
